# Get access to Order ID or Checkout Token on Checkout Thank You page using Shopify Checkout Extensions

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, shopify

I'm using Shopify's checkout UI extensions and react to add a "How did you hear about us" form on the Thank You page. I've figured out how to render the form and grab the value from the submitted form but I need a way to correlate the response to either the order ID or the checkout id/token. From what I understand, the checkout extensions run inside a web worker so you don't have access to the checkout_token local storage object or any of the order data. Any ideas how I can get access to this data and then store it either in my own database or ideally in a metafield on the order itself?

My react code is below

```
import {
  reactExtension,
  BlockStack,
  View,
  Heading,
  Text,
  ChoiceList,
  Choice,
  Button,
  useStorage,
  TextField,
} from '@shopify/ui-extensions-react/checkout';
import {useCallback, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
// Allow the attribution survey to display on the thank you page.
const thankYouBlock = reactExtension("purchase.thank-you.block.render", () => <Attribution />);
export { thankYouBlock };

const orderDetailsBlock = reactExtension("customer-account.order-status.block.render", () => <ProductReview />);
export { orderDetailsBlock };
function Attribution() {
  const [attribution, setAttribution] = useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  // Store into local storage if the attribution survey was completed by the customer.
  const [attributionSubmitted, setAttributionSubmitted] = useStorageState('attribution-submitted')

  async function handleSubmit() {
    // Simulate a server request
    setLoading(true);
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
      // Send the review to the server
      
      
      console.log('Submitted:', attribution);
      setLoading(false);
      setAttributionSubmitted(true)
      resolve();
    }, 750)});
  }

  // Hides the survey if the attribution has already been submitted
  if (attributionSubmitted.loading || attributionSubmitted.data === true) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <Survey title="How did you hear about us ?" onSubmit={handleSubmit} loading={loading}>
      <TextField 
        name="sale-attribution"
        value={attribution}
        onChange={setAttribution}
      />
    </Survey>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `useApplyMetafieldsChange()` defined in **Metafields API** for Checkout UI Extensions

https://shopify.dev/docs/api/checkout-ui-extensions/2024-01/apis/metafields

Comment: From the looks of things, this is only available during the checkout process, not on the Thank You page.

Comment: I keep getting the following error: ExtensionUsageError: Uncaught ExtensionHasNoMethodError: Cannot call 'applyMetafieldChange()' on target 'purchase.thank-you.block.render'. The corresponding property was not found on the API.

Comment: @Daelan did you ever find a workaround for this? I'm also trying to either get an order ID from the thank you page (or add a metafield).

Comment: @JasonB No, I still haven't figured out a way to do this.